# create / update modelStructure

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

1. what is API to create new model based on modelStructure (i.e. converted from external source)?
2. how to store modelStructure changes i.e. after applying Staging API and receiving updated modelsStructure with suggested furniture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we offer no public API for storing externally generated modelStructure in our database, you would need to store it yourself

it's planned for API version 3 ( Q3 / Q4 )

a possible manual workflow:
wrap your modelStructure in a json like below and
save it as filename.model3d.json

then manually drag and drop it into the editor to save it
https://spaces.archilogic.com/3d/template/empty

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "modelStructure": [
    {
        "type": "wall",
        "x": -2,
        "z": -0,
        "l": 4,
        "ry": 120,
        "children": [
            {
                "type": "door",
                "x": 2.2,
                "children": [],
                "y": 0,
                "z": 0,
                "ry": 0,
                "l": 0.9,
                "w": 0.15,
                "h": 2
            }
        ],
        "y": 0,
        "w": 0.15,
        "h": 2.4
    }
  ]
}
```